# Cannot refer to an instance member of a class

Tags: vb.net, xaf

i would like to use the second property LogoWidth to set the width on the first property but im getting the "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from a shared method"
If there's anyone that can help i'll appreciated

```
<DetailViewLayoutAttribute(LayoutColumnPosition.Left, "Header Logo", LayoutGroupType.SimpleEditorsGroup, 1)>
<VisibleInListView(False), DevExpress.Xpo.DisplayName("Logo"), ImmediatePostData> '<RuleRequiredField("Logo", DefaultContexts.Save)>
<ImageEditor(ListViewImageEditorMode:=ImageEditorMode.PictureEdit,
DetailViewImageEditorMode:=ImageEditorMode.PictureEdit, ListViewImageEditorCustomHeight:=85, DetailViewImageEditorFixedHeight:=160, DetailViewImageEditorFixedWidth:=160)>
<Size(SizeAttribute.Unlimited)>
    Public Property Logo() As Byte()
        Get
            Return GetPropertyValue(Of Byte())("Logo")
        End Get
        Set
            '   If True Then
            SetPropertyValue(Of Byte())("Logo", Value)
            '  End If

        End Set
    End Property

    <DetailViewLayoutAttribute(LayoutColumnPosition.Right, "Header Logo", LayoutGroupType.SimpleEditorsGroup, 1)>
    <VisibleInListView(False), DevExpress.Xpo.DisplayName("Width"), ImmediatePostData> '<RuleRequiredField("LogoWidth", DefaultContexts.Save)>
    Public Property LogoWidth As Integer
        Get
            Return _LogoWidth
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            SetPropertyValue(NameOf(LogoWidth), _LogoWidth, Value)
        End Set
    End Property}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as instance members can be modified/called/are visible only by instances. The code below gives you a small piece of concept but here you can get more info about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared

```
Class ClassTest

    Public Property TestIsCalled As Integer

    Public Sub IncreaseTestByInstance()
        TestIsCalled += 1
    End Sub

    Shared Sub IncreaseTestByEveryWhereInNameSpace()
        ' Error
        ' Error - You MUST TO increase test by an instance method not by a shared method
        ' as TestIsCalled not exist when you call here as is an Instance Member not a Shared Member  
        TestIsCalled += 1
    End Sub

End Class
```

So based on your code the solutions are two:

1. Change your Method (that you want to set LogoWidth inside it) in an
   instance `Sub` or `Function` (what is it)
2. or change those two Properties in `Shared Property`.

All depends by your app scenarios.

Comment: Thanks the width is set on the attribute DetailViewImageEditorFixedWidth:=160

Comment: You code is not clear. There is two Properties and remains is mystery. However refer to message you have posted “Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from a shared method ” the issue is that the answer above explain.
Somewhere (in you code, we doesn’t see where as it’s limited) is a Shared Method that’s call Instance Members. You should find where.

Comment: Also you must know that the Attributes are classes and have Properties, Methods etc., those also may be Shared or Instance members.